# Clojure multimethod on class OR keyword

Tags: clojure, multimethod

Suppose I have this multimethod

```
(defmulti m (fn [v] [(:type v)]))

(defmethod m [Object] [k] (prn "Object"))

(defmethod m [:mykwd] [k] (prn "mykwd"))
```

When I call it with subclass of `Object`, it correctly dispatches to the first implementation:

```
(m {:type String})
"Object"
```

With the `:mykwd` it also works as expected:

```
(m {:type :mykwd})
"mykwd"
```

But when I provide another keyword I get an exception:

```
(m {:type :anotherkwd})
#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'm'
for dispatch value: [:anotherkwd] (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)>
```

How exactly does this dispatch work?

Is it possible to preserve this behavior for class inheritance and still have a "default" implementation that catches *all* keywords?

**EDIT** This example is simplistic, but I need it to work with binary functions. My real need is below. I don't see how I could apply `:default` to it.

```
(defmulti m (fn [arg mp] [(class arg) (:type mp)]))
```

Then I'm looking for a way to define it for the case when `arg` is `nil` and `(:type mp)` is anything. This works when value for `:type` is a class, but not for *any* keyword:

```
(defmethod m [nil Object] [arg mp] (prn "Whatever"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your `:type` dispatch with a custom function that returns a default value when `:type` is `nil`.  Same for `class`.  Then you can dispatch on a vector of keywords.  Add the keywords to a hierarchy if you need inherited behavior.

Answer (score 5):

There is a default:

```
(defmethod m :default [x] :oops)
```

Reference:

Check http://clojure.org/multimethods at the bottom of the page.